# Getting error AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Tags: python, dataframe, date, datetime, lambda

I'm getting an error

> 'str' object has no attribute 'strftime'

from this code of mine:

```
from datetime import datetime, date
analysis_dataframe.loc[:,'order_period'] = analysis_dataframe.date.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m'))
analysis_dataframe.head(10)
```

and I have a column "date" with dates in format like that:

[image: column date]

How can I fix this error?

Thank you

Comment: What does the `-03:00`etc. mean in your input (date/time strings)? Is that an offset from UTC?

Comment: ...if so I'd suggest to simply convert to UTC datetime; e.g. `pd.to_datetime(df['order_period'], utc=True)`. After that you can easily re-format to string; `.dt.strftime("%Y-%m")`.

Answer (score 2):

`strftime` is a member function of `datetime` class.
You called the function on x: `x.strftime('%Y-%m')`. The error message suggests that x is an object of type `str`, i.e. it is a string.

It looks like your `analysis_dataframe.date` is an array / series of formatted datetime strings instead of the actual datetime.
Therefore, in order to use the strftime function, you need to parse the date string into a `datetime` object first, then call the strftime function:

```
... = analysis_dataframe.date.apply(lambda x: datetime.fromisoformat(x).strftime('%Y-%m'))
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, since [strftime](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) method expects pandas datatime object first convert it:

```
analysis_dataframe.date  = pd.to_datetime(analysis_dataframe.date)
```

Now you command should work

```
analysis_dataframe.order_period = analysis_dataframe.date.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m'))
```